# Code formatting apps

Tags: php, variables, naming-conventions

I'd like to change the way I name variables, from `$var_name` to `$varName` (or `$_varName` for certain protected variables)

Is there an app that can help me do these changes to my old code too, automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer
It should be able to fix most of your Coding Standards issues in your current codebase. I haven't tried to tool myself though, so I have no experience with it.

Comment: I installed the sublime plugin but nothing happens when I select on "sniff this file" from the menu :s

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your scripts on dreamweaver or on  notepad++ then use the find-replace/replace all. If you just want to change those variables.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) has a good search and replace functionality with preview...

Check this [tutorial](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/3/16/Multifile-search-and-replace-in-Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ has a powerful refactoring engine.
It is not free though, it does provide a 30day evaluation.

I've personally always used Eclipse both for Java, C++ and PHP. Eclipse can do the same as phpstorm , but I find phpstorm engine more sophisticated since it is specially written for PHP